# Versioning docker images in ECR - tagging

Tags: git, docker, versioning

We are versioning master Jenkins(docker image) and storing in ECR with tag `0.1.$(git rev-parse --short head)`.

---

Does this create collision in versioning of images?

What is the better approach for versioning docker image?

Comment: I think that's not a valid [semantic version number](https://semver.org), if your workflow depends on such things, and it's not ordered (which is later, `0.1.abcdef0` or `0.1.01234567`?), but it will be unambiguous.

Comment: @DavidMaze how do I maintain ordering? Without giving explicit number like minor number. Shall I give timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you need to version only the master branch builds.

The fastest and the easiest solution will be to use a timestamp of the latest commit, in format `YYMM.DDHH.MMSS-$(git rev-parse --short head)` as a version. This will comply the semver rules and will be comparable

E.g `2002.1018.1524-abcdef12345` means that it has been built from a commit `abcdef12345` that was committed on February 10, 2020 at 18:15:24